# Highcharts-ng not updating to reflect underlying data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I've run into an issue with the newest (1.0) release of [Highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng): the chart no longer updates to reflect the underlying data.

[Here's a Plunker demonstrating how it SHOULD work (highcharts-ng v0.0.13)](https://plnkr.co/edit/hc7UbBOhiSn0CxPNaMwI?p=preview)

[And here's a Plunker demonstrating what happens in the 1.0 release (nothing)](https://plnkr.co/edit/cs5D1ZYPIcxULYb2THtn?p=preview)

I've looked through the Highcharts-ng docs and haven't been able to find anything about the chart not updating anymore. Does anyone have any input on how to get around this?

Demo app controller:

```
angular.module("app", ['highcharts-ng'])
  .controller("AppController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.title = "Click 'add a point' to see chart update";

    // Chart configuration object.
    $scope.chartConfig = {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      series: [{
        data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7],
        id: 'series1'
      }],
      title: {
        text: 'Hello'
      },
      xAxis: {

      }
    };

    $scope.addPoint = function(){
      $scope.chartConfig.series[0].data.push(Math.random());
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plunkr uses Highcharts 4.2.4 which does not support `chart.update()` method yet. Highcharts-ng 1.x requires Highcharts 5+.

```
    <script data-require="highcharts@*" src="https://code.highcharts.com/5/highcharts.js"></script>
```

example: https://plnkr.co/edit/7rXbYUqoFpeRUnYmQaA9?p=preview